# Obtain device path from pyudev with python

Tags: python, usb, glib, pyudev

Using pydev with `python-2.7`, I wish obtain the device path of connected devices.

Now I use this code:

```
from pyudev.glib import GUDevMonitorObserver as MonitorObserver

def device_event(observer, action, device):
    print 'event {0} on device {1}'.format(action, device)
```

but `device` return a string like this:

> (u'/sys/devices/pci0000:00/pci0000:00:01.0/0000.000/usb1/1-2')

How can I obtain a path like `/dev/ttyUSB1` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Device(u'/sys/devices/pci0000:00/pci0000:00:01.0/0000.000/usb1/1-2')` is a *USB device* (i.e. `device.device_type == 'usb_device'`). At the time of its enumeration the `/dev/tty*` file does not exist yet as it gets assigned to its *child* *USB interface* later during its own enumeration. So you need to wait for a separate *device added* event for the `Device(u'/sys/devices/pci0000:00/pci0000:00:01.0/0000.000/usb1/1-2:1.0')` which would have `device.device_type == 'usb_interface'`.

Then you could just do `print [os.path.join('/dev', f) for f in os.listdir(device.sys_path) if f.startswith('tty')]` in its `device_added()`:

```
import os
import glib
import pyudev
import pyudev.glib

context = pyudev.Context()
monitor = pyudev.Monitor.from_netlink(context)
monitor.filter_by(subsystem='usb')
observer = pyudev.glib.GUDevMonitorObserver(monitor)

def device_added(observer, device):
    if device.device_type == "usb_interface":
        print device.sys_path, [os.path.join('/dev', f) for f in os.listdir(device.sys_path) if f.startswith('tty')]

observer.connect('device-added', device_added)
monitor.start()

mainloop = glib.MainLoop()
mainloop.run()
```

Answer (score 1):

I find this solution:

```
def device_event (observer, action, device):
    if action == "add":
        last_dev = os.popen('ls -ltr /dev/ttyUSB* | tail -n 1').read()
        print "Last device: " + last_dev
```

I know... is horrible.