# usb automatic detection in python for linux env

Tags: python, linux, serial-port, usb, pyserial

I'm using polling command(glob('/dev/tty[A-Za-z]*')) in python to detect usb devices connected to my linux pc in regular interval for my application. Is there any way to detect usb devices connected automatically?

Comment: Can you use the `dbus` module?

Comment: `pyudev` code to monitor `tty` device hot plug https://stackoverflow.com/a/39885881/1778421

Answer (score 0):

Here is a start. You can find your usb vendor [here](http://www.the-sz.com/products/usbid/). You got to code yourself a `current_list_usb`, set a time interval to check so you can compare and see if a new device is attached or not. Some code to use when importing usb module:

```
import usb, usb.core, usb.util, usb.backend.libusb1

...snippet...

#    usb.core.find()
# find our device

dev = usb.core.find(idVendor= ...., idProduct= ....)
#dev_1 = usb.util.find_descriptor(cfg, find_all =True)

# was it found?
if dev is None:
    raise ValueError('Device not found')

#x = dev.set_configuration()
#print (dev)
#print (help(usb.core))
if usb.core.find(find_all=True, bDeviceClass=7) is None:
    raise ValueError('No printer found')
```

Answer (score 0):

The normal way to do this is to make a `udev` rule that tells your program a new `tty` exists.

A custom udev rule may look something like this(let's call it `/etc/udev/rules.d/50-custom-tty.rules`:

```
KERNEL=="ttyUSB[0-9]+", RUN+="/usr/bin/my-program"
```

[Here's](http://reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html?) a good guide on writing udev rules.

In this case, the program `/usr/bin/my-program` will run whenever a new `ttyUSB` device is created in /dev; udev will set a bunch of environment variables to tell you exactly what was just plugged in.  You can then notify your main program that a new `ttyUSB` exists, and it should use it.  Note that whatever program you run should be small, as otherwise the `udev` daemon will kill it if it takes too long.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using libudev and creating a udev monitor object to detect hotplugged devices.  Here is a starting point for you to learn about libudev and its monitor feature:

https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/libudev.html

There might be a good Python library already that wraps udev so you can use its features without writing C code.