# How to monitor usb devices insertion?

Tags: python, linux, usb, dbus, pyudev

I am trying to monitor for USB devices when they get plugged in.
A couple of test scripts fail that I am pretty sure should have worked.

```
import pyudev

context = pyudev.Context()
monitor = pyudev.Monitor.from_netlink(context)
monitor.filter_by(subsystem='usb')

for device in iter(monitor.poll, None):
    if device.action == 'add':
        print('{} connected'.format(device))
```

^^Does nothing. No error, no output.

I try

```
import dbus
bus = dbus.SystemBus()
obj = bus.get_object('org.freedesktop.NetworkManager', '/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager')
obj.GetDevices()
```

output the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "crap.py", line 4, in <module>
    obj.GetDevices()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 70, in __call__
    return self._proxy_method(*args, **keywords)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 145, in __call__
    **keywords)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 651, in call_blocking
    message, timeout)
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: No such interface '(null)' on object at path /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager
```

dbus blocks me on both Linux Mint and a Pi3

How do I monitor for USB devices in python3?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8110310/simple-way-to-query-connected-usb-devices-info-in-python

Comment: @AaditTrivedi thats all 2.7 and win code. I am using 3.5 and Linux. I couldn't get any of it to work. I can ls /dev it, but I was looking for a proper library to use, if possible.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39885881/1778421

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pyudev` accesses the  linux `udevadm` tool. with this device attach / detach events are monitored with `udevadm monitor`

what happens if you invoke `udevadm monitor` with python subprocess call ?

```
  from subprocess import call
  call(["udevadm","monitor"])
```

what happens if you use `MonitorObserver` from pyudev ?

have you tried to invoke python ( script ) as root ?

the following two variants are working for me without root and invoked as script with `-i` option :

```
from pyudev import Context, Monitor

context = Context()
monitor = Monitor.from_netlink(context)
device = monitor.poll(timeout=None)
if device:
    print('{0.action}: {0}'.format(device))
```

-

```
from pyudev import Context, Monitor, MonitorObserver

context = Context()
monitor = Monitor.from_netlink(context)
monitor.filter_by(subsystem='usb')
def print_device_event(device):
    print('background event {0.action}: {0.device_path}'.format(device))
observer = MonitorObserver(monitor, callback=print_device_event, name='monitor-observer')
observer.daemon
observer.start()
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [USBMonitor](https://pypi.org/project/usb-monitor/), which acts, in fact, as a wrapper of [pyudev](https://pyudev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) when you are running on Linux systems.

You should install it with

```
pip install usb-monitor
```

And then just trigger the monitor daemon, as you would do it with [pyudev](https://pyudev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

```
from usbmonitor import USBMonitor

# Define the `on_connect` function
on_connect = lambda device_id, device_info: print('{} connected'.format(device_id))

# Create the Monitor instance
monitor = USBMonitor()

# Start the daemon
monitor.start_monitoring(on_connect=on_connect, on_disconnect=None)
```

It should avoid you from some low-level problems like this, also avoiding, by the way, the OS dependency.